# How to disable line breaks and enable spaces only once in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

***[About the problem I'm having]***

I'm currently improving my Swift skills by mimicking the structure of the profile field in Twitter app.

In the Twitter mobile application, when you press the line break button in the profile edit, the line break is just typed in the space, not the line break. And even if you press the line feed button more than two consecutive times, only one space will be created.
How can such a specification be achieved?

***[What I tried to do to solve this problem]***

```
TextView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
TextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets()
```

I thought I could achieve the same specs as twitter by writing the above code and erasing the top and bottom margins, but I couldn't.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8FGI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with the following code.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
       textView.text = textView.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: " ")
}
```